# Better way to verify if current bar is within a specified timeframe than using 'timestamp'?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

For certain levels I need to verify if the current bar (or a level) is within a certain time range.

For example to verify if we are in the current month, I use the following:

```
bool dMonth = year(timenow) == year(time) and month(timenow) == month(time)
```

Problem:
It is static and does not allow me to utilise custom timeframes added to the chart/my Tradingview settings (unless I add another line of code for every timeframe).

Alternatives I tried (nor really successful):
Using the Security function to check if the current bar is within the selected timeframe always returns true (since it returns a series)

**Ask:**
Whats the recommended/best way you'd go for to check if a price/bar/level is within a defined time range (D, W, M, 3M, 12M, 12h, 2D, ... it varies since I use the same for different strategies which involve different timeframes - which is the dilemma and reason I am looking to write a Method/Function but simply seem not to get well enough)

Any pointer into the right direction is much apreciated.